# How to make discord.py custom prefixes system?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make custom prefixes system for my discord bot on python.   How can I make it?

Comment: Do you know how to find out if a string starts with another string? When you tried to solve the problem yourself what did you come up with?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are talking about letting each server have a custom prefix. If you are using the async branch, I would suggest this. Make a file in the same directory as your .py file named `prefixes.txt`. After that, just use this code, and it will do the rest:

```py
import discord

bot = discord.Client()

def get_prefix(guild_id):
    file = open('prefixes.txt') 
    for line in file.readlines():
        line = line.split(',')
        if(line[0] == str(guild_id)):
            return line[1]
    return '!'

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    prefix = get_prefix(message.guild.id)
    command = message.content.split(' ')[0].replace(prefix, '')
    if(message.content.startswith(prefix)):
        if(command == 'some_command_name'):
            #do stuff

        if(command == 'prefix'):
            file = open('prefixes.txt')
            newfile = ''
            for line in file.readlines():
                lineSplit = line.split(',')
                if(lineSplit[0] == str(message.guild.id)):
                    newfile += str(message.guild.id) + ',' + message.content.split(' ')[1]
                else:
                    newfile += line
            file = open('prefixes.txt', 'w')
            file.write(newfile)
            await message.channel.send('The prefix for this server is now `' + message.content.split(' ')[1] + '`')
                    

bot.run('token')
```

Comment: I tried this code, but i got an error:
```Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Максим\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "5.py", line 29, in on_message
    await message.channel.send('The prefix for this server is now `' + message.content.split(' ')[1] + '`')
IndexError: list index out of range```

Comment: @IAmLegend did you make sure to put a prefix after you type the command?

Comment: i'm getting the confirmation message that the prefix was changed but it doesnt atually change. when i go to my prefixes.txt after changing, my editor offers to reload to show the new file. when i reload, it's still a blank file. so it looks like its writing in the file, but not actually writing anything

Comment: @IAmLegend hmm may be a problem with the editor then. What editor do you use?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a custom prefix by passing a `command_prefix` argument when creating an instance of your bot:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "custom_prefix_here")
```

or this if you're using the rewrite version:

```
client = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "custom_prefix_here");
```